# How to make pipeline in Gitlab only for web interface for non-master branch? (run pipeline button)

Tags: gitlab-ci

Problem:
I have two jobs in my pipeline, which I want to run only by "Run pipeline" button
I need to run this jobs for any branch. But when I choose any non-master branch, gitlab show me "Pipeline cannot be run. No stages / jobs for this pipeline."

First, I configured jobs with no 'rules' keyword but with 'only' keyword:

```
  only:
    refs:
      - api
      - web
```

What I have to do to make my manual-triggered pipeline runnable?

My resent CI:

```
stages:
  - test
  - publish


.run_branch_from_gui:
  only:
    - branches
    - tags
  except:
    - master
  when: manual

compile_and_test_branch_manually:
  stage: publish
  extends:
    - .run_branch_from_gui
  script: "echo 'test'"

publish_docker_image_branch_manually:
  extends:
    - .run_branch_from_gui
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  dependencies:
    - compile_and_test_branch_manually
  stage: publish
  script: "echo 'publish'"
```

I have tried also:

```
   rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
```

but with no effect: still have "***Pipeline cannot be run. No stages / jobs for this pipeline.***" when I click on "Run pipeline" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your complete pipeline I would suggest you use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules), and check if `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is `web` (possible values for this variable are described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)). This will run the job only if it is triggered manually.

```
rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

Comment: run pipeline button popup tells me that "Pipeline cannot be run.
No stages / jobs for this pipeline."  when I try to run non-master branches. I can run only pipeline for master.

Comment: both variants start to work. May be they were not running cause of that branches did not have proper config